# How to export JSDoc types for a JavaScript library that will be published to npm

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have searched web for this, even looked at TypeScript issues on GitHub (5k+ issues) but could seem to find a way for it; example;

```json
// my-module/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ESNext",

    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "include": ["index.js"]
}
```

```js
// my-module/index.js

/** @typedef {{ name: string, surname: string, age: number }} User */
/**
 *
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {string} surname
 * @param {number} age
 * @returns {User}
 */
const NewUser = (name, surname, age) => {
  return { name, surname, age };
};
export default NewUser;
```

```js
// app.js

import NewUser from "my-module"
```

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'my-module', 'node_modules/my-module/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)
```

If I run TypeScript compiler and generate d.ts files that does work but I don't want a compiler step and unnecessary files everywhere, I want to export types directly from JS file with JSDoc. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77501254/edit) the question to include a [mre]? The contents of all files in your `"my-module"` package and the consuming package are necessary, as well as steps for reproducing the error(s), software versions, etc. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to emit declaration(.d.ts) files. Run `tsc --declaration --outDir dist --noEmit false`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html)